# Flutter Gridview Builder lag when coming back to the screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a gridview.builder that fetches images from an API, images are already compressed to a max of 70kb each. I am also using pagination usin to fetch more data. When the grid crosses 30+ images the scrolling becomes choppy and when I go to a page by clicking on any image and then I come back many images load again everything again. I am maintaining the state using IndexedStack. And back animation is also stuttering. What am I doing wrong here?

Gridview Builder Code:

```
 GridView.builder(

                              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              itemCount: postsList.posts.length,
                              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                crossAxisCount: 3,
                                crossAxisSpacing: 3,
                                mainAxisSpacing: 3,
                              ),
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return ProfilePostImageCard(
                                  length: postsList.posts.length,
                                  post: postsList.posts[index],
                                  stringOfPostID: stringOfPostID,
                                );
                              })
```

ProfilePostImageCard

```
class ProfilePostImageCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final ProfilePostModel post;
  final String stringOfPostID;
  final int length;

  ProfilePostImageCard({Key key, this.post, this.stringOfPostID, this.length}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => ProfileFeedsPage(
                  currentMemberImage: CurrentUser().currentUser.image,
                  listOfPostID: stringOfPostID,
                  postID: post.postId,
                  logo: CurrentUser().currentUser.logo,
                  country: CurrentUser().currentUser.country,
                  memberID: CurrentUser().currentUser.memberID,
                )));
      },
      child: Container(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 1,
              child: CachedNetworkImage(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                imageUrl: post.postAllImage,
              ),
            ),
            post.dataMultiImage == 1
                ? Positioned.fill(
              child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                    child: Image.asset(
                      "assets/images/multiple.png",
                      height: 2.5.h,
                    ),
                  )),
            )
                : Container(),
            post.postType == "Video" || post.postType == "svideo"
                ? Positioned.fill(
              child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.video_collection,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 2.5.h,
                      ))),
            )
                : Container(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Full Code

```
SmartRefresher(
          enablePullDown: true,
          enablePullUp: selectedIndex == 1 ? false : true,
          header: CustomHeader(
            builder: (context, mode) {
              return Container(
                child: Center(child: loadingAnimation()),
              );
            },
          ),
          footer: CustomFooter(
            builder: (BuildContext context, LoadStatus mode) {
              Widget body;

              if (mode == LoadStatus.idle) {
                body = Text("");
              } else if (mode == LoadStatus.loading) {
                body = loadingAnimation();
              } else if (mode == LoadStatus.failed) {
                body = Container(
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      border: new Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 0.7),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                      child: Icon(CustomIcons.reload),
                    ));
              } else if (mode == LoadStatus.canLoading) {
                body = Text("");
              } else {
                body = Text("No more Data");
              }
              return Container(
                height: 55.0,
                child: Center(child: body),
              );
            },
          ),
          controller: _postRefreshController,
           onRefresh: _onRefresh,
          onLoading: () {
            if (selectedIndex == 0) {
              _onLoading();
            } else {
              print("blog");
            }
          },

          child: ListView(
            physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: [
              profileLoaded == true
                  ? ProfileCard(
                      userImage: userImage,
                      totalPosts: totalPosts,
                      followers: followers,
                      following: following,
                      bio: bio,
                      name: name,
                      shortcode: shortcode,
                      list: list,
                    )
                  : Container(),
              TabBar(
                indicatorColor: Colors.black,
                tabs: <Tab>[
                  Tab(
                    child: Text(
                      "Posts",
                      style: blackBold.copyWith(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 10.0.sp),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    child: Text(
                      "Blogs",
                      style: blackBold.copyWith(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 10.0.sp),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    child: Text(
                      "Channel",
                      style: blackBold.copyWith(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 10.0.sp),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
                controller: _tabController,
                onTap: (int index) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedIndex = index;
                    _tabController.animateTo(index);
                  });
                },
              ),
              IndexedStack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  GestureDetector(
                    onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
                      if (details.delta.dx < 0) {
                        setState(() {
                          _tabController.animateTo(1);
                          selectedIndex = 1;
                        });
                      } else if (details.delta.dx > 0) {
                        setState(() {
                          _tabController.animateTo(2);
                          selectedIndex = 2;
                        });
                      }
                    },
                    child: Visibility(
                      child: Container(
                        child: hasPosts == true
                            ? GridView.builder(
         
                                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                itemCount: postsList.posts.length,
                                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                                  crossAxisSpacing: 3,
                                  mainAxisSpacing: 3,
                                ),
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return ProfilePostImageCard(
                                    length: postsList.posts.length,
                                    post: postsList.posts[index],
                                    stringOfPostID: stringOfPostID,
                                  );
                                })
                            : Container(),
                      ),
                      maintainState: true,
                      visible: selectedIndex == 0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
                      if (details.delta.dx < 0) {
                        setState(() {
                          _tabController.animateTo(2);
                          selectedIndex = 2;
                        });
                      } else if (details.delta.dx > 0) {
                        setState(() {
                          _tabController.animateTo(0);
                          selectedIndex = 0;
                        });
                      }
                    },
                    child: Visibility(
                      child: Container(
                        child: hasPosts == true
                            ? Column(
                                children: [
                                  ListView.builder(
                                    controller: widget.scrollController,
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                    //physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                    itemCount: blogsList.blogs.length,
                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                      var blog = blogsList.blogs[index];
                                      return PersonalBlogCard(
                                        blog: blog,
                                        index: index,
                                        lastIndex: blogsList.blogs.length - 1,
                                      );
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0.h),
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                      children: [
                                        GestureDetector(
                                          onTap: () {
                                            if (currentPage > 1) {
                                              setState(() {
                                                hasBlogs = false;
                                                currentPage = --currentPage;
                                              });
                                              getBlogs();
                                            }
                                          },
                                          child: CircleAvatar(
                                              radius: 3.0.h,
                                              backgroundColor: primaryBlueColor,
                                              child: Icon(
                                                Icons.arrow_back_ios_outlined,
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                              )),
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          "Page " + currentPage.toString() + "/" + totalPages.toString(),
                                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11.0.sp),
                                        ),
                                        GestureDetector(
                                          onTap: () {
                                            if (currentPage < totalPages) {
                                              setState(() {
                                                hasBlogs = false;
                                                currentPage = ++currentPage;
                                              });
                                              getBlogs();
                                            }
                                          },
                                          child: CircleAvatar(
                                              radius: 3.0.h,
                                              backgroundColor: primaryBlueColor,
                                              child: Icon(
                                                Icons.arrow_forward_ios_outlined,
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                              )),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              )
                            : Container(),
                      ),
                      maintainState: true,
                      visible: selectedIndex == 1,
                    ),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
                      if (details.delta.dx < 0) {
                        setState(() {
                          _tabController.animateTo(0);
                          selectedIndex = 0;
                        });
                      } else if (details.delta.dx > 0) {
                        setState(() {
                          _tabController.animateTo(1);
                          selectedIndex = 1;
                        });
                      }
                    },
                    child: Visibility(
                      child: Container(
                        child: hasPosts == true
                            ? StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                                addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
                                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                crossAxisCount: 3,
                                itemCount: postsList.posts.length,
                                mainAxisSpacing: 3,
                                crossAxisSpacing: 3,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return ProfilePostImageCard(
                                    length: postsList.posts.length,
                                    post: postsList.posts[index],
                                    stringOfPostID: stringOfPostID,
                                  );
                                },
                                staggeredTileBuilder: (index) {
                                  return StaggeredTile.fit(1);
                                },
                              )
                            : Container(),
                      ),
                      maintainState: true,
                      visible: selectedIndex == 2,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
                index: selectedIndex,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution. Evict the image from cache on dispose method and no more lag on screen transition.

```
class ProfilePostImageCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfilePostImageCard({Key key, this.url}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State createState() => new _ProfilePostImageCardState();
}

class _ProfilePostImageCardState extends State<ProfilePostImageCard> {

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // needs to match the url and scale from below
    CachedNetworkImage.evictFromCache(widget.url);
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 1,
              child: CachedNetworkImage(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                imageUrl: post.postAllImage,
              ),
            ),;
  }
}
```

Comment: but that will reload everything again right?

Comment: A workaround would be to clear the cache when you click the back button and then pop the screen. The lag must be caused due to the memory consumption of the network images. Something like this would help. await DefaultCacheManager().emptyCache(); Navigator.of(context).pop();. But doing this would refresh the cached images in the Home screen though.

Comment: Try images with low weight. The only correct way to do it.